# iOS Native Application - Requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I am supporting for one existing native iOS application. For this am able to generate IPA successfully from Xcode but while generating build from devops am facing the issue:

> Requires a provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature

How can I get past this error and build for my device?

Comment: push notification feature is also  enabled at identifiers in apple settings

Comment: Hi @Pinki, did you manage to get past this? I am also facing this error now

Answer (score 0):

Though I had setup up the correct profile for the "Release" build, the "Debug" build needed it's own profile, which I had neglected to generate.

Answer (score -3):

A Provisioning Profile must be installed on each device your application code should run on. Each Development Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID.

Devices specified in the Development Provisioning Profile can be used for testing only by those individuals whose Development Certificates are included in the profile. To create :

- Login to the developer account connected to your project, and under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Profiles -> Register a New Provisioning Profile by clicking the add new button.
- Choose for which purpose provisional profile is required.

  ```
  a. For developement purpose. (the app can be downloaded only in registered devices if the application is in development stage. For this, The device UDID is required to be added in device list).

  b. For distribution purpose ( The provisonal file required for uploading app in the app store)
  ```
- After Selecting above, click continue.
- Choose your Appid (i.e. Bundle id) from the list and click continue.
- After registering, download the provisional profile (File with extension name.mobileprovision will get downloaded) and double click the file to the Xcode project to include the provisional certificate to be added.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.I have a profile how would i know is it development / distribution from apple developer account?

Comment: In the profiles section ->  TYPE will be displayed as Development / App Store / Adhoc . Note: Distribution profiles do not need Device IDs.

Answer (score -4):

you need to follow below steps

- go to developer account
- make provisioning profile for bundle identifier that you are using
  Adhoc(test) or Distribution(production)
- enable push notification
- download the certificate
- click on the certificate

Comment: @Shyan: I have mentioned in my question itself about this push notification feature is enabled in developer account

Comment: great! did you create the provisioning profile against your bundle identifier?